# Trying to get rid of the address bar when using ChocolateChip-UI

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile-safari, chocolatechip-ui

I've been using ChocolateChip-UI (http://www.chocolatechip-ui.com/) for a couple of days, and really like the way it manages to map the look to established mobile standards.

One problem I have with adapting my site to CC-UI has been my inability to make the address bar on scrolling. I tried everything, including meta tags, or even the hack with scrolling to 1px at `onLoad`. Nothing worked. As you can see, even the [demo](http://chocolatechip-ui.com/demo) they have does not seem to make the address bar disappear.

How can I fix this? I really need those 40-50px on the top. I think that the address bar, especially on iOS older than v7, breaks the consistency of the design, and consequently lowers the attention of the user

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about this in the CHUI Google Group.  You can reach it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chocolatechip-ui/XOr7b8HGNK8

From Robert Biggs answer on this

> ```
> $('body').addClass('hideGlobalNav');
> Then have some CSS in your document's header for a custom style:
>
> body.hideGlobalNav #global-nav {
>     display: none !important;
> }
> body.hideGlobalNav #articleWithoutGlobalNav {
>     top: 0 !important;
> }
> ```
>
> Then, you'd need to remove that class from the body tag when the user
>   navigates away. I'm not sure how the navigation is set up in your app,
>   whether the user leaves by going back or forward, but you can handle
>   that in several ways. You can add event listeners for navigation and
>   when the user is leaving #articleWithoutGlobalNav, then you would
>   remove 'hideGlobalNav' from the body tag. You could do something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> $('article').on('navigationend', function(e) {
>    // e.target is the current article that loaded
>    if (e.target.id === 'articleWithoutGlobalNav') {
>  $('body').addClass('hideGlobalNav');
>    } else {
>           $('body').removeClass('hideGlobalNav');
>    }
> })
> ```